# Rails URL's doesn't appear in Google search results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, seo

First of all excuse my english I know that it isn't the best. The thing: I got a Rails application, I already generate the sitemap and inside of it there are the doctor's urls, because my app serves as a medical directory, so let's say that I want to Google: "Michael Green" and indeed there is a doctor with that name inside the app, and I generated the sitemap with it's URL, and all the meta tags as keywords, title and description with that name. When I go to Google it's impossible to find that doctor, even if I use Google custom searches and another tools. It's an API, but I serve HTML in order to Google see the important data first and to make the application crawlable.

I know that I'm not a SEO magician but, I think that I put al the neccesary data to make that "doctor" visible for Google, also my static pages as: Contact, information or the main page, these appear on Google results, but the doctors doesn't, the URL for doctors is something like: app.com/doctors/michael-green, and still nothing. So once again excuse my english and I'll appreciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: How long does your website exist? Are there links from external websites that are listed on Google to your website? Did you tell Google about your sitemap - for example via the Google Webmaster Tools?

Comment: @spickermann About a week, sitemap lives in AWS S3, but I tell robots.txt to look at that direction, even when I check Woorank, it says that sitemap was found and everything. I don't have external links, maybe because of that?

Comment: You need to wait longer. Google doesn't index new pages that fast. That might take weeks or even month to get a useful page rank. And more important you need backlinks, because as long as no other website links to your application Google assumes that no one cares about your site and therefore there is no benefit in adding it to the index.